# fantasy book scientist arrives in dwarves field and teaches him to make aluminum so he can be considered a wizard in this world

Tags: story-identification, magic, technology, dragons

Cannot remember the title or author of this fantasy book. Scientist invented a machine that landed them in an alternate world in the field of a dwarf who had been trying to find the recipe for aluminum so he is considered an official Wizard.  The scientist also helps a knight by putting ground polished glass in his helmet so he can see.  This was a very funny book.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78659/looking-for-a-time-travel-fantasy-scifi-novel-from-the-late-80s-early-90s

Answer (score 2):

I just finished re-reading that trilogy. Simon Hawke, [The Reluctant Sorcerer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/674289.The_Reluctant_Sorcerer) (1992), [The Inadequate Adept](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/674281.The_Inadequate_Adept) (1993), and [The Ambivalent Magician](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/502306.The_Ambivalent_Magician) (1996).

Let's see, the dwarf is a leprechaun, the knight is a nearly blind bandit that 'Brewster Doc' makes lenses for, and aluminum is the Philosopher's Stone.

[image]