# Looking for a time travel fantasy/scifi novel from the late 80s/Early 90s

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Ok, I remember borrowing this book from a friend back in 1993.  I seem to recall the name being The Inept Adept, but I can't find anything related to this name except a piece from the 2000s that doesn't fit the description.

The book was the first in a series about a socially awkward/oblivious scientist from the present that develops a method of time travel using buckyballs.  He travels to the middle ages (fantasy style), and falls in with a small group led by a woman.  He keeps giving them small inventions from the future (he makes soap, so the female leader doesn't have to smell how bad her men smell; he grinds glasses for one of the men who can't see well) and as a result they consider him a wizard.

The only thing I can remember about the villain is that as the novel progresses, he hints that he can “hear” the book's narrator.  I remember it being a cool concept.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In [Simon Hawke's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Hawke) **Reluctant Sorcerer** trilogy, fullerene (as in Buckminsterfullerene aka buckyballs)  is a highly necessary component of Brewster's travelling machine.

**Consists of three books:**
The Reluctant Sorcerer (1992)
The Inadequate Adept (1993) -- *this is the one whose title you almost remembered.*
The Ambivalent Magician (1997)

[The Reluctant Sorcerer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446362603)

> Bumbling genius Dr. Martin Brewster accidentally transports himself to
>   a parallel universe where odd creatures abound and magic really works.
>   When the locals mistake Brewster for a sorcerer, he must devise an
>   escape or incur the wrath of the real magicians.

[The Inadequate Adept](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446362468)

> The second entry in The Reluctant Sorcerer series by the author of the
>   bestselling Wizard series. Marvin Brewster is the Reluctant Sorcerer,
>   trapped in a parallel universe populated with gossiping dragons,
>   walking bushes, capitalist leprechauns, and an evil wizard, who has
>   captured his only means of escape--his time machine.

[The Ambivalent Magician](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446365211)

> Trapped in a paralled universe, Dr. Marvin Brewster marshals his
>   renegade nation of brigands, dragons, trolls, vampire elves, and the
>   runesword Dwarfkabob to challenge evil wizard Warrick. Aware that he's
>   the dastardly villain of a nonstop rollicking adventure romp, Warrick
>   plays the role of destiny and changes the path of the ambivalent
>   magician--while it's being written.